# PROC SQL in SAS - All Pairs of Items

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset in which I need to look at all pairs of items that are together from within another group. I've created a toy example below to further explain.

```
BUNCH    FRUITS
1        apples
1        bananas
1        mangos
2        apples
3        bananas
3        apples
4        bananas
4        apples
```

What I want is a listing of all possible pairs and sum the frequency they occur together within a bunch. My output would ideally look like this:

```
FRUIT1    FRUIT2     FREQUENCY
APPLES    BANANAS    3
APPLES    MANGOS     1
```

My end goal is to make something that I'll eventually be able to import into Gephi for a network analysis. For this I need a Source and Target column (aka FRUIT1 and FRUIT2 above).

I think there are a few other ways to approach this as well without using PROC SQL (Maybe using PROC TRANSPOSE) but this is where I've started.

---

SOLUTION

Thanks for the help. Sample code below for anyone interested in something similar:

```
proc sql;
    create table fruit_combo as
    select a.FRUIT as FRUIT1, b.FRUIT as FRUIT2, count(*) as FREQUENCY
    from FRUITS a, FRUITS b
    where a.BUNCH=b.BUNCH and and not a.FRUIT= b.FRUIT
    group by FRUIT1, FRUIT2;
    quit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest approach is to do a cartesian (full) join of the table to itself, on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.FRUIT ne t2.FRUIT.  That will generate the full combination set, which you could then summarize.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the copy/paste version of above.  A simple reading shows errors - duplicate rows of counts for banana-apple and apple-banana.  To get to the desired result an additional restriction was required (a.FRUIT gt b.FRUIT).

```
data FRUITS ; 
input  BUNCH    FRUIT $;
cards;
1        apples
1        bananas
1        mangos
2        apples
3        bananas
3        apples
4        bananas
4        apples
;
run;


proc freq data=have ;
tables fruits; 
run;


proc sql;
    create table fruit_combo as
    select a.FRUIT as FRUIT1, b.FRUIT as FRUIT2, count(*) as FREQUENCY
    from FRUITS a, FRUITS b
    where a.BUNCH=b.BUNCH 
     and a.FRUIT ne b.FRUIT
     and a.FRUIT gt b.FRUIT
    group by FRUIT1, FRUIT2;
    quit;

proc print ; run;
```