# Constructing All Possible Pairs within Groups

Tags: r

I have a large amount of graph data in the following form. Suppose a person has multiple interests.

```
person,interest
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,5
2,2
3,2
3,5
...
```

I want to construct all pairs of interests for each user. I would like to convert this into an edgelist like the following. I want the data in this format so that I can convert it into an adjacency matrix for graphing etc.

```
person,x_interest,y_interest
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,2,3
2,1,5
2,1,2
2,5,2
3,2,5
```

There is one solution here: [Pairs of Observations within Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488321/pairs-of-observations-within-groups) but it works only for small datasets as the call to  `table` wants to generate more than 2^31 elements. Is there another way that I can do this without having to rely on `table`?

Comment: What happened to `2,5,2`?

Comment: @RichardScriven: Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'person', we get the `unique` pairwise combinations of 'interest' to create two columns ('x_interest' and 'y_interest').

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[,{tmp <- combn(unique(interest),2)
       list(x_interest=tmp[c(TRUE, FALSE)], y_interest= tmp[c(FALSE, TRUE)])} , by =  person]
```

NOTE: To [speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn), `combnPrim` from `library(gRbase)` could be used in place of `combn`.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
interest = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L)), .Names = c("person", "interest"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: This fails on my actual large dataset. The problem appears to be in combn and combnPrim: Error in rep.int(0L, NSET * NSEL) : invalid 'times' value In addition: Warning message: In combnPrim(unique(interest), 2) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @RyanRosario   I couldn't reproduce the error.  If you an show a small reproducible example that show the error, I can look into it